# How does recursion works here?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree

**This is the main file:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 BTFunction bt=new BTFunction();
 bt.insert(5);
 bt.insert(15);
 bt.insert(10);         
 bt.insert(7);
 }
```

**This is the class BTFunction:**

```
public class BTFunction {
BTNode root=null;

void insert(int data){
root=BTinsertion(data,root);

}

BTNode BTinsertion(int data,BTNode n){
    if(n==null){
        n=new BTNode(data);
    }
    else{
            if(n.right==null)
            n.right=BTinsertion(data,n.right);   
            else
            n.left=BTinsertion(data,n.left);   
        } 
    return n;
    }
```

I understand the first 3 insertions(i.e. root, right and left) but when a new value(i.e. 7) is inserted, how does the function works. 
According to me when insert(7) is implemented, it should just search for root.next and root.right which both are not null now. So, it should not do anything.

**Can you explain the recursive process, specially when more values are added.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens when `bt.insert(7);` is called:

`n` is not null, so we move to the else block. `n.right` is not null, so we move to the next else block. Here we call `BTinsertion` with `n.left` as *the root*.

Running `BTinsertion` a level down, `data` is still 7, and `n` is our node with value `10`.

`n` is not null, but `n.right` *is* null, so the 7 node will be added to the right of node 10.

`return n` is called, so our node with value 10 is now a node with a root value and a value for `n.right` (7). Hope that makes sense.